# Why use stopping times rather than a deterministic sequence to localise a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I am a beginner on stochastic processes

I am wondering why , to localise a martingale, require the existence of one non-decreasing sequence of stopping times  [$ \tau_1 , \tau_2$,...] such that the corresponding stopped processes $\{M_{\tau_n \land t} \}$ are all martingales, rather than simply require the existence of one increasing infinite partitioning sequence [$t_1 \lt  t_2 \lt ... \lt t_n \lt ... , t_n \rightarrow \infty$] such that the stopped processes $\{ M_{t_i \land t} \}$ are all martingales ?

I mean, what is to be gained by having stopping times rather than a deterministic sequence here ?

Comment: Regarding your comment to gt6989b I am tempted to ask another question (I wouldn't want to drastically change an existing one) which is: Can someone give me an example of a process that is a local martingale but does not satisfy your deterministic time conditions.  That might get at why local martingales are weaker.  (I originally said this backwards).

Answer (score 0):

Stopping time is more general. Sometimes, you don't know what a particular time will be, e.g. the time the process hits $5$ for the first time is not constant, but is a stopping time.

Comment: would that be the same as requesting that the stopped processes {M t i ∧t } be martingales for any  increasing partition [t1 ... tn ..., tn →∞ ]   ?

Comment: @user3203476 not 100% sure, leaning yes. Perhaps you want to follow advice of muaddib above...